# New child appears twice after adding it to treeListView (an objectListView control)

Tags: c#, windows, objectlistview

I use the `treeListView` control from `objectListView`.

The base is the file explorer example from the demo code.

After adding a new child (file object) it appears twice. In the correct branch and in last branch of the tree.

This is my code:

```
private void AddNewFile()
{
    if(treeListView.SelectedObject == null)
        return;
    //<-----------

    // get the current selected node
    MyFileSystemInfo fsInfoOfCurrentNode = (MyFileSystemInfo)treeListView.SelectedObject;

    // build path for new file in the path of the current node
    string newFilePath = Path.Combine(fsInfoOfCurrentNode.FullName, "New file.txt");

    // create the new path
    File.Create(newFilePath);

    // create the file info object
    MyFileSystemInfo newFsInfo = new MyFileSystemInfo(new FileInfo(newFilePath));

    // add it to the treeListView
    treeListView.AddObject(newFsInfo);
}

public class MyFileSystemInfo : IEquatable<MyFileSystemInfo> 
{
    // this class wrapps  System.IO.FileInfo and System.IO.DirectoryInfo
    // It's from the objectListView explorer demo code 

    // Equals is implemented
    public bool Equals(MyFileSystemInfo other) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Control before adding the new file - `AnyFolder` is selected:

[[image: Control before adding the new file[1]]

Control after adding the new file - `NewFile.txt` appears twice:

[image: Control after adding the new file]

**Edit**

Using `treeListView.AddObject()` here is completely  wrong.

It should be enough to add the file to the wanted folder an run a refresh. But this currently leads to an internal error in the treeListView.

Comment: Can you set break point on that line    treeListView.AddObject(newFsInfo); Debug it and see if it stop two times on it.

Comment: @RadinGospodinov stops only once. After reading some more documentation it seems, thas AddObject() is only suitable for adding `new root nodes`. Seems to be the complete wrong way :(